# current_action not returning actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application_controller I've added:

```
def instantiate_controller_and_action_names
          @current_action = action_name
          @current_controller = controller_name
      end
```

so that I show/hide certain fields in my views depending on the current action.  For example, when adding a new user, I want the ability to show a password field to be filled out, but when editing a user, I don't want the password field to display.

The problem I'm having is that @current_action only returns a value of 'new' when creating a new record, but isn't returning a value when I'm editing a record (e.x.- http://localhost:3000/users/6/edit), or if I use the inverse and check if the @current_action != 'new'...in both cases my field is still being displayed.

```
<%if @current_action != 'new'%>
   <tr><td>AAAAAAA</td></tr>
   <%else%>   
   <tr>
    <th class="">Password</th> 
    <th class="">Password Confirmation</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
    <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td> 
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

What is happening that 'edit' isn't being returned and/or is there a better/best practice way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the controller action, why do you not test your object? You can see if your object is a new record or not with this method

`<% if f.object.new_record? %>
  Your code for new object
<% else %>
You code to edit object
  <%end%>`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to set value of action

You can access it in views like this

```
    action_name  or params[:action]     #return the current action

    controller_name  or params[:controller]     #return the current controller
```

And use it easily.........

```
       <%if action_name != 'new'%>
           <tr><td>AAAAAAA</td></tr>
       <%else%>   
           <tr>
           <th class="">Password</th> 
          <th class="">Password Confirmation</th> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
         <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td> 
         </tr>
      <%end%>
```

And if you want your code the reson is not rendering to not call it.Add this line in

application controller and check

```
           before_filter :instantiate_controller_and_action_names
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the easiest way to get your controller and action names is really to just use the params. So.

```
def current_action
  params["action"]
end

def controller_name
  params["controller"]
end
```

Give that a try.